# DirectXTK C++ : How do you use the Spritebatch.Draw() function with overloaded for RECT?

Tags: xna, c++, directx

I am trying to make use of the DirectXTK's SpriteBatch for the C++ version on github. Which is heavily based on the one for XNA. However I can't seem to get the darned thing to work properly.

I have no idea how to fill in the data for RECT. And the closes thing I have found was in SimpleMath::Rectangle.

SimpleMath::Rectangle appears to have a number of overloads to accommodate RECT, however using it as an argument apparently results in visual studios giving a really vague error. Something about their being no overloads to support it.

Answer (score 1):

RECT is the classic Win32 rectangle structure documented on See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897.aspx)

```
typedef struct _RECT {
  LONG left;
  LONG top;
  LONG right;
  LONG bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT;
```

It provides the left,top corner and the right,bottom corner pixel location.

`Rectangle` should be able to convert to `RECT` implicitly, but only if you have `using DirectX::SimpleMath;` to pull it into the namespace.

I cover using RECT for `SpriteBatch` in the sprites [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures).

Comment: Thank you! Can you also help me fix this problem here? I am sorry if the solution is simple, I've been mentally burned out in the past few days turning some terrible code into frankenstein's monster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356285/directxtk-spritebatch-and-viewport-centering